# Error running using rpy2 for survival analysis

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm trying to perform survival analysis with R with rpy2 in ipython.

The following formulation fails:

```
%Rpush df
surv_fit = surv.coxph("Surv(start, end, status) ~ x", data=df)
> RRuntimeError: Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

But if I do it all using r magic, it works:

```
%Rpush df
%R surv.fit <- coxph(Surv(start, end, status) ~ x, data=df)
```

Is there an issue with the Surv object?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `%Rpush` is pushing the variable to R.

Your first example would then have to be:

`surv_fit = rpy2.robjects.r("""
  surv.coxph(Surv(start, end, status) ~ x, data=df)
""")`

Comment: Is there another way to push the dataframe to R that would allow the first formulation? I tried to use the pandas function, but it failed.